# Lightswitch 2012, using EF to query not attached datasources

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a `LightSwitch project` with a **attached database**, but I want to fill a control of one of my screens with data from a data source which `can't be attached`.

To connect with this data source I must use a `value of my model as Connection string`.

Which is the best way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

why dont you just use a Model layer, and use RIA services to connect?

http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Forum/tabid/63/aft/89/Default.aspx